# Phonegap - Should I include JS vendor files in my git repository?

Tags: javascript, cordova, adobe

If I want to use [Adobe build](https://build.phonegap.com/) cloud for my Phonegap application should I commit the vendor js files like jquery-mobile in my git repository?

Is there a way to avoid it like specifying dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You dont need to commit it to git.. After installation of app it can still download jquery and jqmobile if you specify the script src in your html. But if you put it i side your app then the app will initialize faster compared to download from cdn.

2) there is nothing like dependency.. Yes if you are using plugins from phonegap you can specify only dependency in config.xml. but not for js libraries.

Comment: So is not considered a bad practice to commit the vendor js in phonegap apps?

Comment: No.. Apps run natively in a webview.. U would get your app much faster if you commit it in apps. Finally its up to you..